# AWS: passing parameters to Lambda from code deploy triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

i have lambda function which creates new launch configuration by passing auto scale group name. it works and 
i have created code deploy and attached a trigger to execute Lambda function when deployment success. but i get this error

> 'targetASG': KeyError Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler ASG =
>   asObj.describe_auto_scaling_groups(AutoScalingGroupNames=[event['targetASG']])
>   KeyError: 'targetASG'

targetASG is my parameter but i don't see anywhere that i can define that (triggers,SNS). how can i pass this parameter from code deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, today CodeDeploy doesn't support a way for customers to pass the additional metadata/parameters when invoking the hook functions.

As a workaround, you will have to implement the logic in the hook function to pull up the target ASG name in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a Lambda endpoint for your SNS and the [SNS page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html).

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon SNS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/home.
2. In the left Navigation pane, click Topics, and then click the topic to which you want to subscribe a Lambda endpoint.
3. Click Actions and then click Subscribe to topic.
4. In the Protocol drop-down box, select AWS Lambda.
5. In the Endpoint drop-down box, select the ARN for the Lambda function.
6. In the Version or Alias drop-down box, select an available version or alias to use. You can also choose $LATEST to specify the latest version of the Lambda function. If you do not want to specify a version or alias, you can also choose default, which is functionally the same as $LATEST. For more information, see AWS Lambda Function Versioning and Aliases.
7. Click Create subscription.

Comment: okay so i have created SNS as above giving alias default and created test which include this
{
  "targetASG": "ASG"
}
but i havent define above parameter anywhere so my lambda function doesn't know it when i trigger SNS from code deploy. any solution?